# Expression québécoise: "Fou comme de la marde". Pourquoi?

Tags: expressions, québec, régionalismes

Quelqu'un en saurait-il d'avantage sur cette expression québécoise (ou du moins, ce qui me semble être une expression québécoise) à savoir, d'où nous provient cette merveilleuse expression ?

> Hey, hier soir le Canadiens de Montréal a gagné contre les Bruins de Boston! J'étais fou comme de la *m**a**rde* !

Je dirais que j’entends quand même assez souvent les gens dire ça. Sans trop pousser la pensée, je ne comprend pas pourquoi on dit ça. Il me semble pas que ce soit si fou que ça de la m...

Est-ce seulement une expression de la Mauricie, du Québec (où j'habite)? Ou bien, est-ce étendu à la francophonie en général ?

### Edit

Il n'est pas tant question ici de "merde" ou "marde", mais bien de la signification même de l'expression. À savoir, comment peut-on être fou comme de la *merde*. Pourquoi avoir prit exemple sur de la merde, plutôt que, par exemple, un chien surexcité. Comme mentionné par Laure, est-ce à cause de l'expression `Crazy as shit` ?

Comment: Je vis en France et je n'ai jamais entendu ça, ce n'est donc pas étendu à la francophonie en général.

Comment: Ça doit être une expression typiquement Québécoise. J'ignore pourquoi ce mot est utilisé, mais je crois que nous aimons beaucoup les mots vulgaires. C'est un peu comme l'expression *ça sent l'cr?ss*. ;)

Comment: @Archa : Tu as raison. Mais ce qui m'apparaît étrange, c'est que je ne comprends pas ce que la "vulgarité" vient faire à ce genre de contexte. Il me semble que ce devrait être quelque chose de plus... fou justement. Non pas de la m..., c'est habituellement assez tranquille.

Comment: Cette expression s'étend (un peu comme de la marde peut-être ?) aussi au nord de l'Ontario

Comment: @SimonDugré Je vis au Québec et je n'ai pratiquement jamais entendu ça, l'hypothèse de l'anglicisme me semble la plus sensée. Peut-être que je me tiens pas assez avec des gens "fou comme de la marde" :p

Comment: @Simon Ce qui est drôle avec les expressions, c'est que c'est parfois très régional! Peut-être est-ce quelque chose que nous disons plus ici, en Mauricie (Trois-Rivières)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Je ne réponds pas vraiment à la question mais mon esprit hexagonal étant stimulé par l'exotisme québécois, j'ai cherché à en savoir plus. D'abord le sens exact : [très content euphorique](http://bit.ly/29TSw0y).
Ensuite, j'ai trouvé qu'il existait une expression synonyme [« fou comme un balai ».](http://www.dufrancaisaufrancais.com/tes-donc-ben-fou/)

Et ensuite, je suis tombé sur le mémoire de maîtrise d'un étudiant québécois :
[*Étude de la langue imagée québécoise générée par la structure comparative adj+ comme*](http://constellation.uqac.ca/1366/1/1480724.pdf) (page 93)

> La folie, phénomène hautement immatériel, est illustrée par des
>   comparants exclusivement matériels. [...]  les comparants zoomorphiques (matériel/ animé/ non-humain), toujours populaires, constituent la moitié des images produites en complément de la structure fou/folle comme ___. Pour ce même sous-ensemble d'images, l'indigène prime sur l'exotique. En ce qui concerne les matériels inanimés (dotés des trait naturel ou artefact), on
>   notera que leur relation avec l'adjectif fou/folle n'est pas toujours évidente; ainsi faut-il considérer fou dans le sens de "Dont le mouvement est irrégulier, imprévisible, incontrôlable" (Petit Robert), pour comprendre le mécanisme de fou comme un foin ou fou comme un balai. Quant à l'item merde, on voit mal en quoi il est associable à l'un ou l'autre des sens de fou.

Pour *fou comme de la marde* cette étude écarte à la fois le désordre mental et le mouvement incontrôlable. Soit, mais peut-on vraiment contrôler ses excréments ?

Une hypothèse à ne peut-être pas négliger est celle trouvée sur [ce fil reddidt](https://www.reddit.com/r/Quebec/comments/2g4o6m/de_o%C3%B9_vient_lexpression_fou_comme_dla_marde/ckfmoyx), à savoir que ce pourrait être une traduction directe de l'anglais *[crazy as shit](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Crazy%20as%20Shit)*. On sait bien que nos amis québécois, par ailleurs ardents défenseurs de la langue française, n'hésitent pas à parsemer leur langage d'expressions venues de l'autre côté de leur frontière d'avec les États-Unis.

Mais cette explication ne me satisferait pas entièrement non plus parce qu'il me semble que le mot *marde* est employé [plus fréquemment au Québec](http://oreilletendue.com/2012/01/04/m-m/) que sa version française ne l'est dans l'Hexagone.

Je finis avec cette remarque de *l'Urban Dictionary* :

> **marde**
>   Quebecker/French Canadian version of the French **merde**, meaning **shit**, though may not be used in the same expressions or situations. You'll hear "Bordel de merde" in France quite often, but "Bordel de marde" just doesn't make any sense in Canada.
>   It is one of the very few French Canadian swears that isn't related to church stuff.

Exemples à lire [sur Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=marde).

<sup>* La transformation du **e** ne **a** est semble-t-il [un trait caractéristique de la parlure québécoise](http://bv.cdeacf.ca/bvdoc.php?no=24165&col=RA&format=htm&ver=old).</sup>

Comment: J'aime bien la façon dont tu en parle. Que ce soit "merde" ou "marde" dans le cas de cette expression, n'importe peu je crois. Même si, en tant que québécois, j'avoue que nous entendons vraiment "marde" plutôt que "merdre" habituellement (outre, l'usuel "Hey merde!").

C'est surtout sur la provenance d'une telle expression que je me questionnais. Ton explication du "crazy as shit" semble être une très intéressante piste cependant.

Comment: Et si je disais _j'étais vraiment fou_ ? ahahah. On peut probablement aller au bout de ce raisonnement-là, mais donc ce ne serait pas la sémantique mais bien l'[intensificateur](https://xkcd.com/798/) à l'américaine... merdeusement, un adverbe...

Answer (score 0):

Often in Quebec French, some words with 'e' can come out more like 'a-e' or 'a':

- (From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quebec_French_phonology):) [ɛː] → [aɪ̯] ~ [æɪ̯], but **[aɛ̯] ~ [æɛ̯] before /ʁ/**; [ɛɪ̯] (unstressed), as in fête [faɪ̯t] ~ [fæɪ̯t], Eng. "party"; **père [paɛ̯ʁ] ~ [pæɛ̯ʁ]**, Eng. "father";

So writing 'marde' for 'merde' in Quebec is like writing 'oot' for 'out' in Scotland, or a bit like 'gonna' instead of 'going to', in other words writing it more like how it actually sounds.

If you haven't seen it already, you might find this site, OffQc, useful, and it often broaches topics like this that you might not necessarily find in a textbook!

https://offqc.com/2013/07/09/5-fun-examples-to-help-further-your-knowledge-of-conversational-french-639/

"That last example used puer la marde, "to smell like shit." And that's not a spelling mistake for merde -- you really will hear marde in Québec.

Merde is also understood, like everywhere in the French-speaking world, but marde is distinctively québécois shit."

Comment: But my question here is much more related to the expression itself. As what "Fou comme de la marde" means, 
regardless it's "marde" or "merde". But more about how can you be crazy as shit, how shit can be crazy? :P Aawwm man, sorry Stack, that means a lots of "shit" or "merde" words in a same page haha.

Comment: @SimonDugré Pardon, j'ai mal compris ! En tant qu'Anglo, je suis d'accord avec les autres sur l'idée d'un calque de l'expression idiomatique Anglais 'crazy as shit'. Cf. aussi la phrase avec le même sens, 'crazy as fuck', pour demonstrer le façon metaphorique plutôt qu'une comparaison littérale [simile en anglais].

Answer (score 0):

Je me suis amusé à penser que l’origine de l’expression « fou comme de la marde » aurait un lien avec l’histoire chrétienne en lien avec les hébreux, je crois, qui ont dû traverser le désert et affamés ont vécus la manne tombée du ciel. Donc ce serait une déformation de « fou comme sous la manne » ??
Gilles Binette, Lyster, Québec, Canada

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).